# Apache - Using Virtual_host and mod_proxy together gives Access Forbidden Error

Tags: apache, virtualhost, mod-proxy

I have Apache Web Server on my Host Machine and also on my Virtual Box Machines. Host Machine's Apache web server is serving my sites perfectly.

I have forwarded requests to my router to port 80 of my Host Machine so cannot configure it be forwarded to my Virtual Machine as well. So I thought of using Apache's Proxy capabilities.

I came across this configuration for Apache so as to forward the requests to the virtual machine when they come.

```
< VirtualHost *:* >
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://192.168.111.2/
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.111.2/
ServerName hostname.example.com
< /VirtualHost >
```

When I am activating this setting on my Web Server all my sites (be it on Virtual Machine or Host Machine) start giving "Access Forbidden" Error.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Regards, 
Nitin

Comment: You know, my question is: How are both `httpd` and Virtual Box able to listen on port 80 on the host? I guess it has something to do with the separate network adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following configuration and got it working  -

```
< VirtualHost *:80 >

        ServerName mydomain.com

        ServerAlias *.mydomain.com

        ProxyPass / http://172.16.0.201

        ProxyPassReverse / http://172.16.0.201

< /VirtualHost >
```

Not sure if there can be a more elegant solution than this one.